# SetOfStacks data structure

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented

The data structure question I was trying to solve is as follows:

> **Stack of Plates:**
>
> Imagine a (literal) stack of plates. If the stack gets too high, it
>   might topple. Therefore, in real life, we would likely start a new
>   stack when the previous stack exceeds some threshold. Implement a data
>   structure `SetOfStacks` that mimics this. `SetOfStacks` should be
>   composed of several stacks and should create a new stack once the
>   previous one exceeds capacity. `SetOfStacks.push()` and
>   `SetOfStacks.pop()` should behave identically to a single stack (that
>   is, `pop()` should return the same values as it would if there were
>   just a single stack).

I am trying to practice better data structure design, so I was looking for some feedback on my code as well as tips for going forward:

```
import java.util.*;

 public class StackOfPlates {

   public class StackNode {
     private int data;

     public StackNode(int d){
       data = d;
     }

     public int getData(){
       return data;
     }
   }

   List<ArrayList<StackNode>> setOfStacks;
   private int stackCapacity;

   public StackOfPlates(int c){
     setOfStacks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<StackNode>>();
     stackCapacity = c;
   }


   void push(int item){
     StackNode s = new StackNode(item);

     if(setOfStacks.isEmpty()){
       ArrayList<StackNode> st = new ArrayList<StackNode>();
       st.add(s);
       setOfStacks.add(st);
     }
     else{
       int index = setOfStacks.size() - 1;
       int currStackSize = setOfStacks.get(index).size();
       if(currStackSize == stackCapacity){
         ArrayList<StackNode> st = new ArrayList<StackNode>();
         st.add(s);
         setOfStacks.add(st);
         setOfStacks.get(index + 1).add(s);
       }
       else{
         setOfStacks.get(index).add(s);
       }
     }
   }

   StackNode pop(){
     int setOfStacksSize = setOfStacks.size();
     if(setOfStacksSize == 0) return null;

     ArrayList<StackNode> lastStack = setOfStacks.get(setOfStacksSize - 1);
     int lastElmtIndex = lastStack.size() - 1;
     StackNode end = lastStack.get(lastElmtIndex);
     lastStack.remove(lastElmtIndex);
     return end;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start! There are some things that can be simplified.

### Reuse of Java classes

Java provides the very helpful class [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) which can behave like a stack. So you can reuse this for easier coding :). There is also a `Stack` class, but that one is synchronized.

### StackNode

There is no real need for StackNode. Just use generics to store the specified item directly into the `Stack`/`Deque`. This also prevents `push`ing and `int` and `pop`ping a `StackNode`, which is inconsistent.

### Split checking capacity, current stack to separate methods

For readability, I would try to split the handling of multiple stacks from popping and pushing, increasing readability. The `push()` only needs to know that there is room and `pop()` needs to clean up after getting the element from the stack.

Also, if there is a method of keeping track of the current stack, the logic for checking also becomes easier.

Something like this:

```
public void push( T item )
{
    //Make room if needed
    ensureRoom();

    //The current stack has enough room to push the item
    currentStack().push( item );
}
```

<sub>(note that this is not thread-safe)</sub>

Besides easier to read, it also becomes easier to refactor. For example, if you decide not to use `Deque` but `Stack` or your own implementation, it is easier to change.

### Error handling

What happens when an empty SetOfStacks gets a `pop()`? You should throw a nice exception to make sure that both your `SetOfStacks` stays consistent and make use the caller gets a nice exception.

### Variable names

`int c` and `int d` are not that great for passing on information about what the integer means. Is `c` capacity? And the initial capacity? Or the maximum capacity?

### Access modifiers

Make sure to apply `public`, `protected` and `private` to make sure you only expose functionality that needs to be exposed, and keep private stuff private.

### Proposed solution

```
public class StackOfPlates<T>
{
    private Deque<Deque<T>> setOfStacks;
    private int     maxStackCapacity;

    public StackOfPlates( int maxStackCapacity )
    {
        setOfStacks = new ArrayDeque<>();
        this.maxStackCapacity = maxStackCapacity;
    }

    public void push( T item )
    {
        //Make room if needed
        ensureRoom();

        //the current stack has enough room to push the item
        currentStack().push( item );
    }

    private void ensureRoom()
    {
        if( setOfStacks.isEmpty()  || currentStack().size() == maxStackCapacity);
        {
            Deque<T> newStack = new ArrayDeque<T>();
            setOfStacks.add( newStack );
        }
    }

    private Deque<T> currentStack()
    {
        return setOfStacks.peek();
    }

    public T pop()
    {
        if (setOfStacks.isEmpty())
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        //Remove top element of last sack
        T elem = currentStack().pop();

        //And remove the last stack if it is emty
        maybeRemoveLastStack();

        return elem;
    }

    private void maybeRemoveLastStack()
    {
        if (currentStack().isEmpty())
        {
            //remove empty stack
            setOfStacks.pop();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clean and thorough feedback, it helped me a lot :)

Comment: As an aside I am just wondering, if I wanted to index into a specific index in setOfStacks in order to push onto a particular stack within the set, could I still use an AarrayDeque or would an ArrayList be better in that case?

Comment: You're welcome.  If you want to index in a specific stack, you change the entire problem :) You need indexed access, so probably the`List` interface fits better.